# RAID5 (md0) isn't mounting (Ubuntu server 16.04)

Tags: mount, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

#### Background:

I'm not a total newbie, but Linux is not my thing.

Current hardware is an old Atom box running 16.04 (It's just a file server).  It has a small system disk and 3 larger disks running in a RAID 5.  Two of those disks are 3TB, one is 2TB (therefore capacity is 4TB). The intention is to replace the 2TB with something larger when it failes (and then rescale everything).

I'm trying to move over to a new server as the old Atom box doesn't have the guts to run Zoneminder (security camera software). I installed Ubuntu sever 17.10 on the new box (Zoneminder has problems with 18.04). I just had an old SSD disk in there - left the RAID drives out of the way to start with, to reduce the risk of damaging the RAID structure etc.

Important data is backed up on another machine, but it's a ballache to copy everything back (and I like a good learning opportunity).

#### Current Situation

When I was happy with the new box, I put the RAID drives in there.  I then went to look at the guides for migrating them to a new box, and saw I didn't have the mdadm.conf file (I'm told will make life easier).  Not a problem (I thought) - hooked the drives back up to the old machine, and then found that it would only boot into emergency mode, with it failing to mount md0.  I've moved a RAID over once before, and it was fine.

Can anyone give me some pointers? I didn't want to dive straight into trying to rebuild the RAID, and make things worse.  The last snippet below (file -s) concerns me slightly - not sure if it is reporting incorrectly because the drives are only being used at 66% capacity, as per above, or I've accidentally buggered things up (I'm pretty sure I didn't do anything when building the new machine; I wasn't sure if these drives would spin down without the SATA cables, so disconnected the power cables).

For now, I've commented out mounting md0 from fstab, so I can SSH into the machine and retrieve the below.

fdisk -l:

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 37.3 GiB, 40007761920 bytes, 78140160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d5c2d

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 73967615 73965568 35.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       73969662 78139391  4169730    2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       73969664 78139391  4169728    2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BED00148-B03F-4585-95D9-9028EDDD153C

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 5860532223 5860530176  2.7T Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sdd: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0C579D0F-E3A5-4282-88C3-641E293C904F

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 5860532223 5860530176  2.7T Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Contents of mdadm.conf:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=6e2607c3:60bf172c:a1c05014:0fda067e name=Gomez:0

# This file was auto-generated on Sun, 30 Mar 2014 10:42:55 +0100
# by mkconf $Id$
```

file -s:

```
nick@Gomez:/$ sudo file -s /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,1), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 1, 4294967295 sectors, extended partition table (last)
nick@Gomez:/$ sudo file -s /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: Linux Software RAID version 1.2 (1) UUID=6e2607c3:60bf172c:a1c05014: fda067e name=Gomez:0 level=5 disks=3
nick@Gomez:/$ sudo file -s /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,1), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 1, 4294967295 sectors, extended partition table (last)
```